# Multiple Facebook Canvas Applications within same web application - CanvasAuthorizeAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

I am having a problem with running multiple Facebook applications under a single Web application.

Similar to this problem:
[Multiple facebook apps under one web application](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4931240/multiple-facebook-apps-under-one-web-application)

I do like the solution suggested here, however the CanvasAuthorizeAttribute uses the FacebookApplication.Current internally and this is a static instance of the FB application within the Web application.

I can't call the .SetApplication method within the controller as I will have concurrency issues.

It would be nice if the FacebookApplication.Current called the Func that is passed into the .SetApplication instead of just calling inside of the .SetApplication.

That way I could pass a function that does my logic for retrieving the correct FB application.

Am I missing something that is already in the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

You can always have your own logic at http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4931240/multiple-facebook-apps-under-one-web-application/4936703#4936703

```
    private IFacebookApplication Current
    {
        get
        {
            var url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
            var app = GetSettingsForUrl(url); 
            // put your custom logic here and return the appropriate IFacebookApplication
            return app;
        }
    }
```

But you should do this during Application_Start where it is still running on a single thread and not in Controller.